# Incorrect Syntax near 'join'

Tags: t-sql

I've got such code:

```
  Select 
  C.ClientId
  ,K.NameShort
  ,C.SetId
  ,C.CaseId
  ,C.ClientCaseNumber
  ,D.Name
  ,Pay.Overpayment
  from CaseDetails as C
  where (C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL) and (C.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)

  join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
  join DocumentDetails as DD on C.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId
  join PaymentDocumentHistory as Pay on DD.DocumentId = Pay.DocumentId
  join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
```

While trying to run it it gives me error about incorrect syntax near 'join'. Unfortunately I have no idea why such error is given..

Comment: Look at the t-sql `SELECT` syntax [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JOIN`s are part of the `FROM` clause. The `WHERE` clause comes after the (entire) `FROM` clause.

```
 Select 
  C.ClientId
  ,K.NameShort
  ,C.SetId
  ,C.CaseId
  ,C.ClientCaseNumber
  ,D.Name
  ,Pay.Overpayment
  from CaseDetails as C
  join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
  join DocumentDetails as DD on C.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId
  join PaymentDocumentHistory as Pay on DD.DocumentId = Pay.DocumentId
  join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
  where (C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL) and (C.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

`join` comes before `where`.

```
  from CaseDetails as C    
  join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
  join DocumentDetails as DD on C.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId
  join PaymentDocumentHistory as Pay on DD.DocumentId = Pay.DocumentId
  join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
  where (C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL) and (C.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JOINS are out of place. You've placed your JOIN after the WHERE Clause.

```
Select C.ClientId
  ,K.NameShort
  ,C.SetId
  ,C.CaseId
  ,C.ClientCaseNumber
  ,D.Name
  ,Pay.Overpayment
  from CaseDetails as C
  join Client as K on C.ClientId = K.ClientId
  join DocumentDetails as DD on C.CaseDetailsId = DD.CaseDetailsId
  join PaymentDocumentHistory as Pay on DD.DocumentId = Pay.DocumentId
  join DebtorDetails as D on C.CaseDetailsId = D.CaseDetailsId
  where (C.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL) and (C.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
```